# Understand math done for endpoint in canvas arc

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, canvas

Given that i want to draw a circle in canvas that looks like below:

[image: angled circle]

Now i am using the **[circliful](https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful)** plugin ,

Now the math done behind the scenes is like so:

```
if (type == 'angle') {
              startAngle = 2.25 * Math.PI;
              endAngle = 2.4;
              circ = 1.53 + Math.PI;
              quart = 0.73 + Math.PI / 0.996;
}
```

The above math gets used like so:

```
 context.arc(x, y, radius, endAngle, startAngle, false);
```

Now i understand the math done for                     startAngle, but why `endAngle = 2.4` ? where does the `2.4` come from ?

I know it works perfectly, Why 2.4 ? can anybody explain ?

The line of code can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/blob/master/js/jquery.circliful.js#L153)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.4 is approximately 76% of a half circle.

The [`context.arc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) function takes angles measured clockwise from positive x. With other words, the 2.4 indicates approximately going from the center to the bottom left at a 45 degree angle.

Similarly in the same code there's a snippet that says `endAngle = 3.13`, which is nearly PI or nearly 180 degrees (so pointing to the left), that's used for half a circle.

Comment: @Aidiakapi Sorry had to down vote as you did not answer the Why 2.4? and you did not at all mention radians or address why radians are used.  I don't consider it an answer.

Comment: @Blindman67 He clearly states that he understands what the math for startAngle does, and with that he implied to understand radians. He asked why they picked 2.4, the answer is because that's the angle that points to the bottom left, simple as that. He didn't ask for a lecture about radians.

Answer (score 1):

**Radians & PI**

Why do almost all graphic functions use Radians?

I see it all the time. People converting from degrees to radians. This question asks why 2.4?

Lets look at a circle. To create a circle we need to sweep a point around another point by 360 degrees. All good we all know 360 degrees. Say we want the circumference of the circle. Easy `2 * PI * radius`. Easy too, say we want the length of the circumference for half a circle. Easy as well `PI * radius`. By what if we want the length of the arc for 80 deg well then its `(80 / 360) * 2 * PI * radius` easy to do but a lot of steps.

If you look at the formula for the circumference `2 * PI * r` you will see that the  `2 * PI` is the number of radians that make a circle. This is why in computer programs we use radians. Most calculations to do with circles will involve PI but if we work in degrees the computer has to convert to radians all the time, this takes up CPU time, and computer programmers hate slow code.

So now  with the `80 deg` which is `0.7R radians` if we want the circumference all we have to do is `0.7 * radius`. One multiplication instead of five, two memory location instead of five. And we don't have to use the irrational number `PI` that is embedded in the angle `0.7R`

**So why 2.4R?**

Because it is easier for the computer to handle radians than degress.

**Use Radians**

Once you get used to using radians you will wonder why you ever wasted your time working in degrees. Personally I never use degrees unless I need to output it as a result or ask it as an input. I then immediately convert it to radians.

**Conversion**

On the canvas the angles start pointing right 0 Radians then move clockwise to pointing down `(PI / 2)` `1.570796327` (gee way to many numbers `1.571` will do. You would need a circle radius 10,000 pixels befor you notice the rounding or better still just use the constant `PI/2`)

So some angles to radians starting with 0 pointing right then clockwise around the circle

```
Deg   Radians   Radians
------------------------
0     PI * 0     0
45    PI / 4     0.785
90    PI / 2     1.571 // down the screen
135   PI * 3/4   2.356
180   PI         3.142 // left
225   PI * 5/4   3.927
270   PI * 3/2   4.712 // up the screen
315   PI * 7/4   5.498
360   PI * 2     6.283 or 0  // back to pointing right
```

Also to convert from Degrees to Radians is `(degrees / 360) * 2 * PI` when `(degrees / 360)` normalises the angle (a range from 0 - 1) then `*2*PI` converts the normalised angle to radians. As `(degrees / 360) * 2` is the same as `(degrees * 2) / 360` so we can divide the top and bottom by `2` to give `(degrees / 180) * PI`

So as a function

```
function deg2Rad (degrees) {
    return (degrees / 180) * Math.PI;
}
```

To convert from radians to degrees normalise the radians `(radians / (PI *2))` then multiply by `360` to give `(radians / (PI *2)) * 360` again we can divide it all by 2 and simlify to get `(radians * 180) / PI`

As a function

```
function rad2Deg (radians) { 
    return (radians * 180) / Math.PI;
}
```

**Differences and Comparisons**

Radius are cyclic just as degrees are. `0Deg` is the same as `360Deg`, `-360Deg`, and `720Deg`, they both point in the same direction. This can be problematic if you are working with any types of angles. Say you want to get the differance between  `10Deg` and `350Deg`. Going clockwise its `340`, going anticlockwise its `20` (use the negative `-20Deg`). But if you look at code to find the dif how to get the -20??

```
var a1 = 10;
var a2 = 350;
console.log(a2-a1); // 340
console.log(a1-a2); // -340 // thats not right
```

To get the `-20` you may consider addding some `if` statments

```
if(a2 > 180){ // to get the smaller angle
   console.log(a2-(a1+360)); // -20  // thats right
}
```

But you will soon find this gets messy as angles can come in at any multiple of 360. What is the angle `-35640deg` and how far is it from `10deg`.

To do this you use the modulo operator in javascript `%` `a = n % m` a is the remainder of `n / m` so if `n = 22` and `m = 10` then `n % m` or `22 % 10` is 2. `5 % 2` is 1 and `128 % 50` is 28.

We can use modulo to quickly get the angle to within a range to compare angles with

```
var a1 = -35640
console.log(a1 % 360); // 0 degs
```

Modulo for negative numbers will result in a negative remainder. What you want when comparing angles is positives. So there is a quick way to get the angle for comparison.

```
var angleDeg = (Math.random()-0.5) * veryBigNum; // get a big angle
angleDeg %= 360; // get the angle in a range between -360 < angle < 360
angleDeg += 360; // remove the negative to 0 < angle < 720
angleDeg %= 360; // redo the remainder 0 <= angle < 360
```

or as one line

```
angleDeg = ((angle % 360) + 360) % 360;
```

Now to find the clockwise and anticlockwise difference between any two angles as a function.

```
function minAngleDif(angle1, angle2){
    angle1 = ((angle1 % 360) + 360) % 360; // get within range
    angle2 = ((angle2 % 360) + 360) % 360; 
    var dif1 = angle2 - angle1;    // get dif
    var dif2 = angle2 - (angle1 + 360); // get diff in opposite direction
    if(Math.abs(dif2) < Math.abs(dif1)){ // fund the samller number
        return dif2;
    }
    return dif1;
}
```

Thus you get the smallest difference in angle between any two angles. As I was showing it all in degrees and this is about radians. Here are the two function that find the difference between any two angle

For minimum difference

```
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2; // create the 360 as radians 
// or some people prefer Tau (I am such a person)
const TAU = Math.PI * 2; // I always capitalized constants as It lets me know it is a constant
function minAngleDif(angle1, angle2){
    angle1 = ((angle1 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; // get within range
    angle2 = ((angle2 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; 
    var dif1 = angle2 - angle1;    // get dif
    var dif2 = angle2 - (angle1 + TAU ); // get diff in opposite direction
    if(Math.abs(dif2) < Math.abs(dif1)){ // fund the samller number
        return dif2;
    }
    return dif1;
}
```

For maximum difference

```
function maxAngleDif(angle1, angle2){
    angle1 = ((angle1 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; // get within range
    angle2 = ((angle2 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; 
    var dif1 = angle2 - angle1;    // get dif
    var dif2 = angle2 - (angle1 + TAU ); // get diff in opposite direction
    if(Math.abs(dif2) < Math.abs(dif1)){ // fund the samller number
        return dif1;
    }
    return dif2;
}
```

For min and max.

```
// result is an object to hold the result. It is optional
function angleDif(angle1, angle2, result){
    if( result === undefined ){
         result = {min:null,max:null};
    }
    angle1 = ((angle1 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; // get within range
    angle2 = ((angle2 % TAU ) + TAU ) % TAU ; 
    var dif1 = angle2 - angle1;    // get dif
    var dif2 = angle2 - (angle1 + TAU ); // get diff in opposite direction
    if(Math.abs(dif2) < Math.abs(dif1)){ // fund the samller number
        result.min = dif2;
        result.max = dif1;
        return result;
    }
    result.min = dif1;
    result.max = dif2;
    return result;
}
```

**Last note on radians just for interest.**

PI is an irrational number. This means that it is a number that is not the result of a fraction of two integers. `0.5` is a rational number it can be written as `1/2` and  `0.2` is `1/5` but for PI there are no two whole numbers that can be used to result in PI. It also means that PI can not be written, the number of decimals in the number PI is infinite. This also means that the computer can not store the number PI it can only ever use an approximation. On Javascript there is a handy constant in the Math API called Math.PI which has a value of 
3.141592653589793  that's 15 decimal places. This is way overkill for almost all calculations. I Have seen people concerned with accuracy create their own constant for PI.

```
var PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
// or
const PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
```

This will not help as Javascript will just round back to the 15 decimal places. Nor will the rounding really affect your calculations as long as you are not using very large or very small numbers.

The value Math.PI is precise enough for all your needs. To give you an idea of how precise. Consider a pixel it is about 0.2mm in size to be out by one pixel due to the rounding of PI you would need to have a screen that is 5,000,000,000,000,000 pixels across (5 million billion pixels) at 0.2mm that would need a screen near 1/10th of a light year in size to be out by just one pixel.

In most cases 4 decimal places is more than enough for your calculations.

Well that covers the it all and more than answers the question. Overkill yes but it's a quiet night..

Comment: I could -1 for "Because it is easier for the computer to handle radians than degress", or for the stating that "Javascript will just round back to the 15 decimal places". For the first, if your architecture doesn't support floating points, or if you need to do some low-level optimization and use fixed-point math, degrees may actually be much faster to compute with. For the second, Javascript (or ECMAScript) doesn't round to 15 decimal places, instead it uses the precision of the underlying format (a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point), which has variable precision. However, I'm going to be petty.

Comment: @Aidiak What does `console.log(3.1415926535897932);console.log(3.1415926535897938)` output. The rounding is done during parsing. It is not a function of the float. All Javascript implementations should use the same float format. Secondly if you are using fixed float to do the calculations and writing in assembly you are still quicker to use radians as the circumference of a circle is still 2 * PI * radius. You will always have to convert to radians if you want the length of an arc given the angle and radius, or for that mater many other attributes of circles spheres and things that use PI.

Comment: So basically you repeated exactly what I said. The truncation happens as a result from following the IEEE 754 standard, not from ECMAScript itself. It's nitpicking, but true. In response to "if you are using fixed float", I said fixed-point math, that means you're using an integer format to represent decimal numbers, using a precision you control. You don't have to write assembly to write optimized code.

Comment: Again try the two numbers output to console in the previous comment and you will see that the numbers are NOT truncated but rounded IEEE defines 4 rounding methods, it does not define truncation.And To be precise  Fixed float is the term used when you define floating point numbers as two integers and is the most optimised way to handle fractions on any system. Fixed-point is similar but different enough to warrant the need to keep them separate.

Comment: You're confusing the rounding modes (which is literally which rounding operations can be done on a floating point) with the parsing of floats from a string. Fixed-point uses a single integer, with a fixed precision, N bits integer, M bits fractional part. It is not necessarily the most efficient way to handle fractions on any system. It all depends on the scenario. In some cases it can really save performance to not have to convert floats into integers (possibly need for indexing purposes), and fixed-point can help. But if there's a dedicated floating point processor, that's usually faster.